# As a body HttpServletRequest always returns CoyoteInputStream and not actual body

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that checks user credentials and if these are correct parses sent JSON. It is working fine but I cannot access JSON. In my code there is a command `InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();` that should read JSON but every time it returns `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@3f1e9348`. Please have a look at my code:

```
@POST
@Path("auth")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String controller(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {


    String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authorization == null) {
        authorization = request.getHeader("authorization");
    }

    String basicHeader = "basic";
    if (authorization != null && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith(basicHeader)) {
        String base64Credentials = authorization.substring(basicHeader.length()).trim();
        String credentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Credentials),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        String[] values = credentials.split(":", 2);
    }

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I try to use `request.getReader()` I get the infamous `IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request` exception. Please see the relevant piece of code:

```
if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()))
        {
            try {
                String req = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I use curl to send `POST`:

```
curl -u myusername:mypasswor -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain your body content by declaring a parameter on your method:

```
public String controller(String body, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
```

But you can also get the JAX-RS implementation to deserialize that JSON to your intended type:

```
public String controller(MyExpectedType body, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
```

This should work because you've declared your expected content type, assuming you have a provider that's applicable (such as jackson-jaxrs...).

Regarding the input stream error: this is probably because the container JAXRS implementation has already parsed the request.

But if you were to process it in a normal scenario, such as in a servlet, you'd still have to correct the way you read it:

The documentation for `getInputStream` state:

> Retrieves the body of the request as binary data using a ServletInputStream. Either this method or getReader() may be called to read the body, not both.

This means that to get the content sent by your client in the body, you need to read the stream:

```
String body = request.getReader().lines()
                      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

You can also use the `Stream`-based API:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[request.getContentLength()];
request.getInputStream().read(bytes);
String body = new String(bytes); //you may need to specify the character set
```

The actual input stream class is implementation-based (container-supplied), so you shouldn't need to be concerned with `CoyoteInputStream`

Comment: As I said, this produces `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request`.

Comment: My comment regarded your first solution. In your edited answer, however, `Stream-based API:` method works fine.

Comment: Edited answer :-)

Comment: Thanks! `MyExpectedType body` is the part I liked the post since that way I get my JSON.